# Java3D Floodfill

Tags: java, java-3d, flood-fill

I need to get a floodfill algorithm working for 3D shapes in Java3D, I have already done 2D shapes, using Buffered Images and Rasters. What I need to do now is to set a 3D point as the seed and floodfill outwards.

Does any one know if it is possible in Java3D or if I need to use a different library?

Comment: I'm afraid that using anything like flood fill in 3D is not really feasible. One has to define shapes using only traingles. So, you could use some Triangulation algorithm to get filled shapes out of closed contours. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well I'm using genetic algorithms to determine best point to start floodfilling in a shape. I've got that working to an extent in 2d, I now have to do it in 3d. It also has to be done so the user can see the shape being filled in.

Comment: Are you using voxels? If not, I don't think flood filling is really well-defined for polygon-based 3D.

Comment: I'm not using Voxels, I had never heard of them but they look interesting so i'll look into them, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I totally forgot about voxels. This is the right direction. But, Darragh, you didn't explain how is your 3d shape defined. How do you define it's borders?

Comment: At the moment I am just following the java3d tutorial and am just using simple Boxes and Spheres as my shapes so far, So my apologies I am still unsure how I will define borders in 3d.

Comment: @Darragh169: from what I've seen 3D Floodfill is non-trivial (unless you use Voxels). What do you want to achieve with it? What is your goal? Simple graphical display or something else?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I want to be able to Display an empty 3D shape(square, sphere, etc) and then show it being filled using a floodfill algorithm. So yeah a simple graphical Display.

Comment: Filling with fluid in the presence of gravity?